# Splitting a column across multiple rows in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

I am using Power BI Desktop.

I have a column where there are multiple values separated by ','.  The value in this column is assigned multiple distinct rows.  I want to split the column and assign a value to each of the rows.  For example:

Original data

| Input SN | Output SN |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1,2,3 |
| b | 1,2,3 |
| c | 1,2,3 |

Desire Result

| Input SN | Output SN |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| b | 2 |
| c | 3 |

I have tried splitting by delimiter on Output SN and then trying to group by input SN, but I can't seem to get to the desired results.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Sussie.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WSlTSUTLUMdIxVorViVZKQuElI3ixAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [#"Input SN" = _t, #"Output SN" = _t]),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Inserted Text After Delimiter" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Text After Delimiter", each Text.BeforeDelimiter( Text.AfterDelimiter([Output SN], ",", [Index]-1),","), type text),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Inserted Text After Delimiter",{"Output SN", "Index"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Text After Delimiter", "Output SN"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

Which transforms
[image]

into

[image]